# Books like Grundlagen der Analysis in French

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for some recommendations for a mathematics (text)book written in French. I am hoping to learn to read and write mathematics in French since I expect to take some mathematics courses that will be taught in French next year.

Basically, I would like a book whose linguistic and mathematical level approaches that of Landau's book [Grundlagen der Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0828401411)- the language should be clear and simple (read: not unnecessarily fancy or ornamental) and the mathematics contained in the book should be comprehensible to someone who has taken a course or two in analysis and algebra. It would be a huge plus if you can recommend a book that also contains a French-English vocabulary at the back like in Landau's book but the recommendation should primarily be based on the clarity of the text and the level of mathematical depth.

Please note that the book you recommend need not be a textbook- it could be lecture notes that are particularly well-written or monographs exploring some topic or even a popular account of mathematics that is relatively easy to understand. Also, the level of the book need not be at the university level. Depending on the book, it might even be preferable if it was at the high school level.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if they would fit the bill, but have you looked at the Bourbaki books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a collection of French mathematics books choose the ones you want they are among the most famous textbooks and problems solving books. and i hope that will help you.

> Cours (Text-books)

Cours de mathematiques Tome 1 - Algèbre, J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide, H.Fraysse

Cours de Mathematiques Tome 2  - Analyse, J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide, H.Fraysse

Cours de Mathematiques Tome 3 - Complements d'analyse, J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide, H.Fraysse

Cours de mathematiques Tome 4 - Algebre bilineaire et geometrie, J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide

Cours de mathématiques spéciales Tome 1 - Algèbre, E.Ramis, C.Deschamps, J.Odoux

Cours de mathématiques spéciales Tome 2 - Algèbre et applications à la géométrie, E.Ramis, C.Deschamps, J.Odoux

Cours élémentaire de mathématiques supérieures Tome 1 - Algèbre, J.Quinet

Cours élémentaire de mathématiques supérieures Tome 2 - Fonctions usuelles, J.Quinet

Cours élémentaire de mathématiques supérieures Tome 3 - Calcul intégral et séries, J.Quinet

Cours élémentaire de mathématiques supérieures Tome 4 - Equations différentielles, J.Quinet

Cours élémentaire de mathématiques supérieures Tome 5 - Géométrie, J.Quinet

Eléments d'analyse Tome 1 - Fondements de l'analyse moderne, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 2 - Analyse fonctionnelle linéaire, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 3 - Analyse sur les variétés, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 4 ,Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 5 - Groupes de Lie compacts et semi-simples, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 6 - Analyse harmonique, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 7 - Equations fonctionnelles linéaires, 1ère partie - Opérateues pseudo-différentiels, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 8 - Equations fonctionnelles linéaires, 2ème partie - Problèmes aux limites, Jean Dieudonné

Eléments d'analyse Tome 9 - Topologie algébrique, topologie différentielle élémentaire, Jean Dieudonné

Mathématiques 3 - Analyse cours et Exercices, E.Azoulay, J.Avignant

Mathématiques 4 - Algèbre, E.Azoulay, J.Avignant

Mathématiques L3 - Algèbre cours complet avec 400 tests et exercices corrigés, A.Szpirglas

Mathématiques L3 - Analyse Cours complet avec 600 tests et exercices corrigés, Jean-Pierre Marco

Roger Godement - Analyse Mathématique 1, Convergence, fonctions élémentaires

Roger Godement - Analyse Mathématique 2, Calcul différentiel et intégral,séries de Fourier,fonctions holomorphes

Roger Godement - Analyse Mathématique 3, Fonctions analytiques, différentielles et variétés, surfaces de Riemann

Roger Godement - Analyse Mathématique 4, Intégration et théorie spectrale, analyse harmonique, le jardin des délices modulaires

Mathematique 2eme annee Cours et Exercices Corriges, C.Deschamps, A.Warusfel

Mathématiques Algebre et geometrie 50% et 50% exercices, G.Auliac, J.Delcourt, R.Goblot

Mathématiques générales 1 ère année cours et exercices corrigés, J.Vélu

Mathématiques méthodes et exercices MP, J.M Monier

Mathématiques TOUT-EN-UN 1ère année cours et exercices corigés MPSI, PCSI, Série E.Ramis, C.Deschamps, A.Warusfel

TD Analyse, 70% Applications 30% Cours, Jean-Pierre Lecoutre, Philippe Pilibossian

Topologie et analyse fonctionnelle cours de licence et 240 exercices et 30 problèmes 
corrigés, Y.Sonntag

Calcul diffrentiel et calcul intégral 3eme année Cours et exercices avec solutions, Marc 
Chaperon

Complement d'analyse, K.Arbenz, A.Wohlhauser

Cours d'Algébre avec énoncés 40 Exercices et 300 Problèmes, J.Querré

Cours de Mathematiques MP-MP', Jean Voedts

> Problems solving (Exercices resolus)

Algèbre Exercices avec solutions, E. Ramis, C. Deschamps, J. Odoux

Analyse Tome 1 - Exercices avec solutions, E. Ramis, C. Deschamps, J. Odoux

Analyse Tome 2 - Exercices avec solutions, E. Ramis, C. Deschamps, J. Odoux

Exercices resolus Tome 1 - Algebre du cours de mathematiques Tome 1, J.M.Arnaudiès

Exercices resolus Tome 2 - Analysee du cours de mathematiques, J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide

Exercices resolus Tome 3 - Complements d'analyse du cours de mathematiques, J.M.Arnaudiès

Exercices resolus Tome 4 - Algebre bilineaire et geometrie du cours de mathematiques, 
J.M.Arnaudiès, P.Delezoide, H.Fraysse

Exercice d'algebre 1, B.Calvo, J.Doyen, A.Calvo, F.Boschet

Exercices d'analyse 1, B.Calvo, J.Doyen, A.Calvo, F.Boschet

Problèmes d'Analyse Tome 1 - Nombres réels suites et séries, Exercices corrigés,Wieslawa 
J.Kaczor, Maria T.Nowak

Problèmes d'Analyse Tome 2 - Continuité et dérivabilité, Exercices corrigés,Wieslawa J.Kaczor,
Maria T.Nowak

Problèmes d'Analyse Tome 3 - Intégration, Exercices corrigés,Wieslawa J.Kaczor, Maria T.Nowak

275 Exercices et Problèmes Résolus de Mathématiques Supérieures, A.Abouhazim, A.Abkari, 
S.R.Nsiri, M.El Mountassir