# A Real Analysis book which is in both French and English Languages.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, mathematical-french

I need a real analysis book which is in both French and English languages. So, it would be great if anybody does have any idea of this issue.

Comment: I think some of Serge Lang's books have French translations. Also, many Mir titles have been translated into multiple Western languages, including some into both French and English (although the quality of the translations is sometimes not the best). Could you say what topics you'd like covered, or name a well-known textbook with coverage similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: Any analysis book with any level is okay. For instance, Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin to Real Analysis by Folland, etc.

Comment: http://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/sciences-fondamentales/mathematiques/licence/principes-danalyse-mathematique Of course, a translation won't be the same as a book written in the French style. The only solution to that problem would be to find an analysis book translated from French to English, but I don't know of any offhand.

Comment: Thanks David for sharing your ideas.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, there's Godement's four-volume work, which has been translated into English. http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Convergence-Elementary-functions-Universitext/dp/3540059237/

Comment: Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis* is in both languages: http://www.amazon.fr/El%C3%A9ments-danalyse-fondements-lanalyse-chapitres/dp/2876472112/ http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Modern-Analysis-J-Dieudonne/dp/1406727911/

Comment: You might have a look at this question: [Books like Grundlagen der Analysis in French](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172616/books-like-grundlagen-der-analysis-in-french). Maybe some of the books mentioned there have English translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there is a large number of books on real analysis or some closely related topic which where published in/translated to both languages. Especially since you said in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622072/a-real-analysis-book-which-is-in-both-french-and-english-languages#comment3306915_1622072) that: "Any analysis book with any level is okay. For instance, Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin to Real Analysis by Folland, etc." This might cover quite wide range of books. So I thought that it might be a good idea to start a CW answer where various users can add books they are aware of.

- [R. Godement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Godement): **Analyse mathématique**. At least some of the four volumes have been translated to English. (As a part of Springer's Universitext series.)
- *[Jean Dieudonné](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Dieudonn%C3%A9)*'s **Traité d'analyse**. Many (if not all) volumes of have been translated to English. (As **Treatise on Analysis** or **Foundation of Modern Analysis**. However, these books might be closer to functional analysis than to real analysis.)
- *Wieslawa J.Kaczor, Maria T.Nowak*: **Problems in Mathematical Analysis** and **Problèmes d'analyse** (three volumes). If I remember correctly, both English text and French text are translation from Polish.
- *N. Piskunov* (or [Piskounov](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola%C3%AF_Piskounov)): **Differential and Integral Calculus** and **Calcul différentiel et intégral**. Translated from the Russian original Пискунов Н.С.: Дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления; published by Mir.
- *W. Rudin:* **Principles of Mathematical Analysis,** translated as **Principes d'analyse mathématique.**
- *W. Rudin:* **Real and Complex Analysis,** translated as **Analyse réelle et complexe.**
- *S. Lang:* **Real Analysis,** translated as **Analyse réelle.**
- *A. N. Kolmogorov, S. V. Fomin:* **Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis, Éléments de la théorie des fonctions et de l'analyse fonctionnelle.** Translations of *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа.*
- All books in Bourbaki's *Elements of Mathematics* series were originally written in French.

Comment: Just a note. Volume 1 of Dieudonné's *Treatise on Analysis* was actually originally published in English as *Foundations of Modern Analysis*. The later volumes were first published in French.